# Heroku/Django project not working locally, maybe a path issue

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am in a project folder that was cloned from heroku. Within the folder I ran

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'pinpoint.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named pinpoint.settings
```

And got this ^ error.

After scouring the internet, someone suggested that I "add pinpoint to my path". Not entirely sure how to do this, but I figured that I must check first if my path has it or not. so I ran

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
... 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Gimbpy-1.0-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

In ^ I didn't see the project folder nor did I see the folder pinpoint that is nested inside of the project folder. Hmm? Where do I go from here. I am attempting to run my project locally in order to make tests before I commit them. Any idea what I can do to fix this? I am very new to this whole "add to path" thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all In the **Second command** while looking for the list of Paths , you have to to run "**python manage.py shell**" not "python", as the former will open python specific to your project.

Note: The **Path to the Directory** in which **manage.py resides**, automatically gets **added to the Path.**

Appending to path is simple ie.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<new_path>)
```

But **before appending any path**, I would **recommend** you give the proper path to **settings file in manage.py file**. it should be relative to directory in which your manage.py resides (so that system can pick it)